# Call to node js server using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

This question might be very simple thing. But I couldnt figurout the issue in my code.

I want to send data to a node js api using jquery ajax call.

This is my **node js API**

```
.post('/createPerson', global.bodyParserJson, function (req, res, next) {           
        console.log(req.body);

      // My code going here
    })
```

This my **ajax** call from client side.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/createPerson",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  { Name: "John", Age: 20 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Sucss');            
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log('Err');

        }
    });
```

API is hit by ajax call, but data is not passing. It comes as empty. I try to call the api using postman and it works well which means json data comes to server side.

Can you give me a clue to find the issue in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JSON.stringify to first serialize your object to JSON string so then your server can understand it's a JSON:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/createPerson",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  JSON.stringify({ Name: "John", Age: 20 }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Sucss');            
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log('Err');

        }
    });
```

This should work